# error: invalid use of member XXX in static member function

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, pointers

I've been trying to figure out how to pass a `QStringList` pointer around between my member functions. For some reason I'm getting an error that says the following:

> mainwindow.cpp:497: error: invalid use of member 'MainWindow::emails' in static member function

```
// global definition
QStringList* MainWindow::emails;
```

mainwindow.h

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow{
    ...
    private:
        static QStringList * emails;
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

size_t MainWindow::WriteMemoryCallback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data)
{
    QString filteredNewLine = plainText.replace("\n"," ");
    QRegularExpression re("[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)");
    QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = re.globalMatch(filteredNewLine);
    QStringList words;
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
        QString word = match.captured(0);
        words << word;
         MainWindow::emails = &words;
         qDebug() << MainWindow::emails
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
   delete emails;
}
```

Comment: Is `WriteMemoryCallback` static? You can't access non-static member variables from a static function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: invalid use of member in static member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391853/error-invalid-use-of-member-in-static-member-function)

Comment: @Thomas you can if you have a pointer to an object that contains the members to be accessed. The callback's `data` parameter looks like a possible way to give the callback such an object pointer.

Comment: thanks for the advice @ Kuba, I removed the solution, should I also remove the actual code solution also?? Thanks

Comment: Quick update I found the solution, I had to declare a static member pointer global. Doing this gave me the ability to pass around the static member to other functions.

Comment: thanks @ Thomas, your tip also gave me insight to why i was getting those errors

Comment: The original question should of course remain, with code.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using curl in your project. There is a C++ binding for curl, but we can make one that leverages Qt.

First of all, let's wrap the global initialization and cleanup in a RAII wrapper:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/curl-50975613
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>

class CurlGlobal {
   Q_DISABLE_COPY(CurlGlobal)
   CURLcode rc;
public:
   CurlGlobal() { rc = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); }
   ~CurlGlobal() { curl_global_cleanup(); }
   CURLcode code() const { return rc; }
   explicit operator bool() const { return rc == CURLE_OK; }
};
```

We'll also need a RAII wrapper around `curl_slist`:

```
class CurlStringList {
   struct curl_slist *list = {};
public:
   CurlStringList() = default;
   explicit CurlStringList(const QStringList &strings) {
      for (auto &s : strings)
         list = curl_slist_append(list, s.toLatin1().constData());
   }
   CurlStringList &operator=(CurlStringList &&o) {
      std::swap(o.list, list);
      return *this;
   }
   ~CurlStringList() {
      curl_slist_free_all(list);
   }
   struct curl_slist *curl() const { return list; }
};
```

The "easy" handle, `CURL*`, can be wrapped in a `QObject`, to leverage its flexibility. This is where we see how to properly implement callbacks using `CURLOPT_xxxDATA`, without any global/static variables:

```
class CurlEasy : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   friend class CurlMulti;
   CURL *const d = curl_easy_init();
   QAtomicInteger<bool> inMulti = false;
   CURLcode rc = d ? CURLE_OK : (CURLcode)-1;
   char err[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
   CurlStringList headers;

   bool addToMulti();
   void removeFromMulti();
   static size_t write_callback(const char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *data) {
      Q_ASSERT(data);
      return static_cast<CurlEasy*>(data)->writeCallback(ptr, size * nmemb);
   }
protected:
   virtual qint64 writeCallback(const char *, qint64) {
      return -1;
   }
   void setWriteCallback() {
      curl_easy_setopt(d, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)this);
      curl_easy_setopt(d, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, (void*)write_callback);
   }
   virtual void clear() {}
```

The `clear` method is used in derived classes to prepare the state before a request gets underway.

The remaining methods wrap and expose the various options, and error handling:

```
public:
   CurlEasy(QObject *parent = {}) : QObject(parent)
   {
      curl_easy_setopt(d, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, err);
   }
   ~CurlEasy() override {
      removeFromMulti();
      curl_easy_cleanup(d);
   }
   CURL *c() const { return d; }
   operator CURL*() const { return d; }
   bool ok() const { return rc == CURLE_OK; }
   QString errorString() const { return QString::fromUtf8(err); }
   bool setUrl(const QUrl& url) {
      rc = curl_easy_setopt(d, CURLOPT_URL, url.toEncoded().constData());
      return ok();
   }
   void setMaxRedirects(int count) {
      curl_easy_setopt(d, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, count ? 1L : 0L);
      curl_easy_setopt(d, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, (long)count);
   }
   void setVerbose(bool v) {
      curl_easy_setopt(d, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, v ? 1L : 0L);
   }
   bool get() {
      if (inMulti.loadAcquire())
         return false;
      clear();
      curl_easy_setopt(d, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
      if (addToMulti())
         return true;
      rc = curl_easy_perform(d);
      if (!ok())
         qDebug() << errorString();
      return ok();
   }
   void setHeaders(const QStringList &h) {
      headers = CurlStringList(h);
      curl_easy_setopt(d, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers.curl());
   }
   void setWriteTo(FILE *);
   void setReadFrom(FILE *);
   void setWriteTo(QIODevice *dev);
   void setReadFrom(QIODevice *dev);
};
```

The details of `setWriteTo` and `setReadFrom` methods can be skipped: they are used to make the `CurlEasy` object interoperate with C files and Qt I/O devices. See the repository for full code.

Now, we need a line parser: a class that uses the `writeCallback` to decode individual lines:

```
class CurlLineParser : public CurlEasy {
   Q_OBJECT
   QByteArray m_buf;
protected:
   qint64 writeCallback(const char *ptr, qint64 count) override {
      const char *start = ptr;
      const char *const end = ptr + count;
      for (; ptr != end; ptr++) {
         if (*ptr == '\n') {
            if (!m_buf.isEmpty())
               m_buf.append(start, ptr-start);
            else
               m_buf = QByteArray::fromRawData(start, ptr-start);
            emit hasLine(QString::fromUtf8(m_buf));
            m_buf.clear();
            start = ptr + 1;
         }
      }
      // keep partial line
      m_buf = QByteArray::fromRawData(start, ptr-start);
      return count;
   }
   void clear() override {
      m_buf.clear();
   }
public:
   CurlLineParser(QObject *parent = {}) : CurlEasy(parent) {
      setWriteCallback();
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void hasLine(const QString &);
};
```

The application-specific filtering of lines can be implemented by listening to the `hasLine` signal.

At this point, we have everything needed to run the synchronous (blocking) requests. Let's postpone the examination of the `CurlMulti` class for a moment, and see how the user interface / demo looks:

```
class Ui : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   CurlLineParser m_curl{this};
   QRegularExpression m_re{"[a-z0-9]+[_a-z0-9.-]*[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)"};
   QStringList m_emails;
   QGridLayout m_layout{this};
   QPlainTextEdit m_view;
   QLineEdit m_url;
   QCheckBox m_async{"Async"};
   QPushButton m_get{"Get"};
public:
   Ui() {
      m_url.setPlaceholderText("Url");
      m_view.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
      m_url.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Preferred);
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_view, 0, 0, 1, 3);
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_url, 1, 0);
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_async, 1, 1);
      m_layout.addWidget(&m_get, 1, 2);
      connect(&m_get, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]{
         m_emails.clear();
         emit requestGet(m_url.text());
      });
      connect(&m_async, &QCheckBox::toggled, this, &Ui::requestAsync);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void requestGet(const QString &);
   Q_SIGNAL void requestAsync(bool);
   void setUrl(const QString &url) { m_url.setText(url); }
   void setAsync(bool async) { m_async.setChecked(async); }
   void processLine(const QString &line) {
      auto it = m_re.globalMatch(line);
      while (it.hasNext()) {
         auto email = it.next().captured(0);
         m_emails.push_back(email);
         m_view.appendPlainText(email);
      }
   }
};
```

The `Ui` has a method that can process lines from any source, and filter them using the regular expression. This class is completely decoupled from the specifics of curl machinery.

Connections between the curl "stack" and the Ui are done from `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   CurlGlobal curlGlobal;
   QApplication app(argc, argv);
   QThread netThread;
   CurlMulti multi;
   CurlLineParser curl;
   multi.moveToThread(&netThread);
   Ui ui;
   QObject::connect(&ui, &Ui::requestGet, [&](const QString &url){
      curl.setUrl(url);
      curl.get();
   });
   QObject::connect(&ui, &Ui::requestAsync, [&](bool async){
      QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&curl, [&curl, &multi, async]{
         if (async) curl.moveToThread(multi.thread());
         curl.setParent(async ? &multi : nullptr);
         if (!async) curl.moveToThread(qApp->thread());
      });
   });
   QObject::connect(&curl, &CurlLineParser::hasLine, &ui, &Ui::processLine);
   curl.setMaxRedirects(2);
   curl.setVerbose(false);
   curl.setHeaders({"Accept: text/plain; charset=utf-8"});
   ui.setUrl("https://gist.github.com/retronym/f9419787089149ad3a59835c2e1ab81a/"
             "raw/8cd88ab3645508ae1243f3aa4ec7c012af4fae7b/emails.txt");
   ui.show();
   netThread.start();
   int rc = app.exec();
   QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&multi, [&]{
      if (!curl.parent())
         curl.moveToThread(app.thread());
      multi.moveToThread(app.thread());
      netThread.quit();
   });
   netThread.wait();
   return rc;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

When the asynchronous option is selected, the `CurlLineParser` object is moved to a worker thread, and made a child of the `CurlMulti` object. The thread wrangling is necessary only because it's OK to flip-flop the configuration between blocking, same-thread implementation and the async, separate-thread implementation. It is of course also possible to the async, same-thread configuration - simply remove all of the `moveToThread` calls.

The `CurlMulti` wraps around `CURLM*` and uses Qt's socket notifiers to interface curl with the event loop. The per-socket notifiers are stored as the per-socket pointer, using `curl_multi_assign`.

```
class CurlMulti : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   friend class CurlEasy;
   struct Notifiers {
      QScopedPointer<QSocketNotifier> read, write, exception;
   };
   CURLM *m = curl_multi_init();
   QBasicTimer m_timer;

   void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *ev) override {
      int running;
      if (ev->timerId() == m_timer.timerId()) {
         m_timer.stop();
         curl_multi_socket_action(m, CURL_SOCKET_TIMEOUT, 0, &running);
         processInfo();
      }
   }
   static int socket_callback(CURL *, curl_socket_t s, int what, void *userp, void *socketp) {
      Q_ASSERT(userp);
      return static_cast<CurlMulti*>(userp)->
            socketCallback(s, what, static_cast<Notifiers*>(socketp));
   }
   static int timer_callback(CURLM *, long ms, void *userp) {
      Q_ASSERT(userp);
      auto *q = static_cast<CurlMulti*>(userp);
      if (ms == -1)
         q->m_timer.stop();
      else if (ms >= 0)
         q->m_timer.start(ms, q);
      return 0;
   }
   int socketCallback(curl_socket_t s, int what, Notifiers* n) {
      if (what == CURL_POLL_REMOVE) {
         delete n;
         curl_multi_assign(m, s, nullptr);
         processInfo();
         return 0;
      }
      if (!n) {
         n = new Notifiers;
         curl_multi_assign(m, s, n);
         n->exception.reset(new QSocketNotifier(s, QSocketNotifier::Exception, this));
         connect(&*n->exception, &QSocketNotifier::activated, [this, s]{
            int running;
            curl_multi_socket_action(m, s, CURL_CSELECT_ERR, &running);
         });
      }
      if ((what & CURL_POLL_IN) && !n->read) {
         n->read.reset(new QSocketNotifier(s, QSocketNotifier::Read, this));
         connect(&*n->read, &QSocketNotifier::activated, [this, s]{
            int running;
            curl_multi_socket_action(m, s, CURL_CSELECT_IN, &running);
         });
      }
      if ((what & CURL_POLL_OUT) && !n->write) {
         n->write.reset(new QSocketNotifier(s, QSocketNotifier::Write, this));
         connect(&*n->write, &QSocketNotifier::activated, [this, s]{
            int running;
            curl_multi_socket_action(m, s, CURL_CSELECT_OUT, &running);
         });
      }
      n->exception->setEnabled(what & CURL_POLL_INOUT);
      if (n->read)
         n->read->setEnabled(what & CURL_POLL_IN);
      if (n->write)
         n->write->setEnabled(what & CURL_POLL_OUT);
      processInfo();
      return 0;
   }
   void processInfo() {
      int msgq;
      while (const auto *info = curl_multi_info_read(m, &msgq)) {
         if (info->msg == CURLMSG_DONE)
            for (auto *c : children())
               if (auto *b = qobject_cast<CurlEasy*>(c))
                  if (b->d == info->easy_handle && b->inMulti)
                     b->removeFromMulti();
      }
   }
public:
   CurlMulti(QObject *parent = {}) : QObject(parent) {
      curl_multi_setopt(m, CURLMOPT_SOCKETDATA, (void*)this);
      curl_multi_setopt(m, CURLMOPT_SOCKETFUNCTION, (void*)socket_callback);
      curl_multi_setopt(m, CURLMOPT_TIMERDATA, (void*)this);
      curl_multi_setopt(m, CURLMOPT_TIMERFUNCTION, (void*)timer_callback);
      int running;
      curl_multi_socket_action(m, CURL_SOCKET_TIMEOUT, 0, &running);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void finished(CurlEasy *);
   ~CurlMulti() override {
      for (auto *c : children())
         if (auto *b = qobject_cast<CurlEasy*>(c))
            b->removeFromMulti();
      curl_multi_cleanup(m);
   }
};
```

Finally, the two separately-defined internal methods of `CurlEasy` that handle its additions and removals from the `multi` object:

```
bool CurlEasy::addToMulti() {
   auto *m = qobject_cast<CurlMulti*>(parent());
   if (d && m && inMulti.testAndSetOrdered(false, true)) {
      QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m, [m, this]{
         curl_multi_add_handle(m->m, d);
      });
   }
   return inMulti;
}

void CurlEasy::removeFromMulti() {
   auto *m = qobject_cast<CurlMulti*>(parent());
   if (d && m && inMulti.testAndSetOrdered(true, false)) {
      curl_multi_remove_handle(m->m, d);
      emit m->finished(this);
   }
}
```

#### See also:

- https://github.com/tarasvb/qtcurl
- https://github.com/pavlonion/qtcurl